# UIScrollView Not Working Properly For iPhone6 and iPhone 6Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, iphone-6

[image]

I have a issue of having gap in between view that are combined in a scrolliew in only iphone 6 and iphone 6plus. It works fine for iphone 5.
I am giving frames through cgrect to the images, text,button, which look fine on the screen for all the phone but getting this design issue. All the data is fetched from WebService,in JSON form and then parsed.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
 if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"second"];
    UIView *contentData = [cell viewWithTag:3];

    NSLog(@"content data height is %f",contentData.frame.size.height);

   // contentData.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UIScrollView *scrollV =(UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0;i<self.categor.bestsellerlist.count;i++)
    {
        UIView *bestsellerview = [[UIView alloc]init];
        bestsellerview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

//
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
            [bestsellerview addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
            bestsellerview.tag = i;

```
        bestsellerview.frame = CGRectMake(i*(((320-30)/2)+5),0,((320-30)/2),(((320-30)/2))*1.79);
        AsyncImageView *asy = [[AsyncImageView alloc]init];
        asy.frame =  CGRectMake((bestsellerview.frame.size.width/2)-((((320-30)/2)*0.75)/2),10,(((320-30)/2)*0.75),(((320-30)/2)*0.85));

        asy.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        NSLog(@"Bestseller view%@",NSStringFromCGRect(bestsellerview.frame));
        NSLog(@"AsyncImage view%@",NSStringFromCGRect(asy.frame));

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:   [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",imageUrl,[[self.categor.bestsellerlist objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"imagefilestd"]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSLog(@"url is %@",url);
        [asy loadImageFromURL:url];
        [bestsellerview addSubview:asy];

        // displayname

        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"yname is %f",asy.frame.origin.y+asy.frame.size.height+10);
        name.text =[[self.categor.bestsellerlist objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"prodname"];
        name.frame =  CGRectMake(0,138,bestsellerview.frame.size.width-5,44);
        [name setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        name.numberOfLines = 3;
        name.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        name.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


        [UtitlityClass setLableLayout:name];
        [bestsellerview addSubview:name];
```

[image]

Comment: can you please write your code too, so we can suggest you changes

Comment: please check your scrollview->check auto layout should not be checked

Comment: I have not used autolayout.. Whole app uses auto resize

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer is not commented.. It looks as if it is commented in the ablove code

Comment: Can you capture a picture of your **Show the size inspector**?

Comment: @SanitLee you can check out the image of tableviewcell size inspecter

Comment: @TalibShabbirHussain Did you found way how to fix it?